# Issue with escape characters in Watir/Cucumber

Tags: watir

Was hoping someone could help me with an issue I am having with escape characters in Cucumber/Watir.

I have automated tests setup. When I perform a search, 1 of the assertions I use to verify that the search has returned the correct result is to check the page for text. So my code looks like this:

```
Then /^I should see the following text: "([^"]*)"$/ do |str|
  assert @browser.text.include?(str)
end
```

Here I pass in the text to search for in the string variable. e.g nike, reebok etc

So in my feature file the step is like this:

```
Then  I should see the following text "search results for nike"
```

This works fine apart from 1 issue. 1 of the sites I am testing has decided to put the search term in double quotes i.e - search results for "nike"

As a result this screws up my test as I need to include the quotes as part of the search term. Therefore I need to put the word nike in escape quotes or else cucumber will recognise the first quotation around the word nike as a closing quotation. (as there is already a double quotes before it)

I have tried various different escape characters but nothing seems to work. For example I have tried the following:

```
\" – double quote
\\ – single backslash
```

Has anyone experienced similar problems and if so, how did you overcome the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the regex rather than the string.

**Problem:** Your current regex says `"([^"]*)"`, which says to match all characters between the quotations that are not quotations. This is not good given that you want to include quotations.

**Solution:** Change the step to the following:

```
Then /^I should see the following text: "(.*?)"$/ do |str|
  assert @browser.text.include?(str)
end
```

The `.*` says to match *all* characters between the quotations. The `?` makes the search lazy (instead of greedy). The `?` is optional in this case, but would be important if there were additional parameters being captured. A good explanation of the greedy vs lazy can be seen at http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html.

Comment: Thanks a million Justin! Just changed the regex to what you said and it now works as expected. Never even occured to me to change the regex. Thanks again!